# How exactly is "salt" generated in PHP password_hash?

Tags: php

I am currently creating a website and adding database to it. I am adding "Create account" option and decided to use "password_hash()" command, so passwords stored on my database are more safe.

I understand how everything works, except I don't get, how salt is generated.

Theoretically it should be following an algorithm to generate different "salts" every time a new user is created, but how does the computer generate the same salt for the user password to compare, when user tries to log in?

Comment: The salt is included in the hashed password.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66989/how-does-a-random-salt-work